# How to keep certain characters intact while using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Working on some text formatting and analysis - I've got a large block of text that I'm trying to break into individual sentences. Obviously, `explode` can do this handily using the punctuation at the end of each sentence.

The problem I'm having is that normal language also contains periods that don't indicate the end of a sentence - such as decimals and abbreviations. For example, "One team anticipates they will break the previous record of 92.49% efficiency, which was set in 1991." will result in two sentences, the second starting with "49%". This is what I'm trying to avoid.

I can safely remove these mid-sentence periods without affecting my analysis, but I need to keep the rest of each string intact - and this is where I'm running into trouble. In the case of the decimal point above, I can match the character with `$str = preg_replace("/[\.]+[0-9]/", "", $str);` - but replacing the match also eliminates the first decimal of the number.

How can I use `preg_replace` and still keep certain characters intact?

---

**UPDATE:**

A couple answers have suggested using a lookahead to match a character without including it in the replacement. While this works for the example given above, this wouldn't work for an abbreviation (eg U.S.) - is there a more general case we can come up with, or at least maybe a counterpart "lookbehind"?

Comment: Interesting case. Do note though that there are more cases that can contain a point, like abreviations and names. Do you want to take this into account to or is it not a problem if these are being parsed as sentences?

Comment: Please show us before and after strings (edit the question, do not put it in a comment).

Comment: @vrijdenker That's a good point, abbreviations especially (eg U.S.) pose the same problem. I'll edit the question to apply to the more general case.

Answer (score 0):

What if you adjusted your regex to match where a number surrounds the decimal... something like this maybe

```
/[0-9]+[\.][0-9]+/
```

**Edit:**

How about a match then a replace?

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]+[\.][0-9]+/", $str, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

then loop throught the $out array and perform the replace on those strings to remove the decimal.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but when replacing this would remove the digits immediately before and after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
[\.](?=[0-9])
```

It uses a lookahead to match a decimal followed by 0-9 but without including the 0-9 in the match.

**Update:**

I took another look at it with your update in mind but I am not able to think of a solution that solves all of the use cases. I was able to make the solution I suggested a little more general to cover more situations with this:

```
[\.](?=[^\s])
```

This looks for a period or decimal point character followed by anything that is not a space, tab, line break, etc rather than just followed by a number. This helps catch a few more things that might cause you issues but it still misses a lot.

This would work for something in this:

"One team anticipates they will break the previous record of 92.49% efficiency, which was set in 1991 in the U.S."

but would fail for something like this:

"One team anticipates they will break the previous record of 92.49% efficiency, which was set in the U.S. in 1991."

As @vrijdenker mentioned, names would be another issue. I just don't know how you distinguish between a period at the end of a sentence and a period after an abbreviated middle initial.

Comment: This might work for this particular example, but what if we need to match something like "U.S." with `"/[A-Z]+[\.]/"`? Is there a "lookbehind" one can use?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\.(?=\d)/", "", $str);
```

Comment: See my comment for @twalters - there are cases where the lookahead wouldn't catch. Is there a more general case we can use?

Comment: Yes, you can use that for abbreviations: (?<=\w)\.(?=\w)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to ignore only points belonging to a number, but also abbreviations, names, etc, just forget about the numbers for a while.

I've set up a fiddle containing some Lorem Ipsum and in the middle I added your example sentence followed by some more abbreviations and a name.

```
<?php


$var = <<<EOT
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tortor velit, facilisis ac malesuada vel, tristique sit amet purus.
Donec magna turpis, iaculis vitae nisl et, porttitor tincidunt augue. Fusce odio tortor, laoreet ut turpis eget, lobortis ultrices lorem.
One team anticipates they will break the previous record of 92.49% efficiency, which was set in 1991. B.T.W.: abbreviations like U.S. and names like I.M. Theman should also be ignored.
Duis lobortis lacus ligula, a lobortis ipsum lacinia in. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis volutpat nisi, non cursus est. Nam pellentesque congue lectus, in auctor erat viverra sit amet. 
Mauris pellentesque magna dolor, in euismod neque mattis eu. Etiam in massa eget eros consectetur iaculis eu in tortor. 
Mauris luctus, nulla ac blandit molestie, augue dui iaculis orci, eu suscipit ipsum mauris a enim. Curabitur vel mauris lorem. Maecenas et metus cursus, posuere nisi vitae, auctor turpi.
EOT;

$var = preg_replace('/[^\.]{2,}\.\s/', '$0[[SPLIT]]', $var);
$lines = explode('[[SPLIT]]', $var);

print_r($lines);
```

If you look at the text you can make up the following logic:

- A point at the end of the sentence should always be followed by whitespace: either a space or a line-break
- An abbreviation is also followed by whitespace. In many cases though it has only one character. A sentence never ends with a single character (I think), so let's say that before the point there must be more than one character not being whitespace or a point.

This logic let to the following regex:

```
/[^\.]{2,}\.\s/
```

As you can see here, that works: http://ideone.com/MkyEcL

Please note the following:

- You may be able to do this with preg_split(), but as you can see in my example I try to keep the text in tact. So I keep the points, the whitespace and the line-breaks. I don't know how to do that with preg_split, so I've combined preg_replace() and explode() instead.
- Also note that I can think of cases that I believe you can't capture. For example the following sentence:

  "I am mr. Theman and I love StackOverflow."

  In this case the abbreviation has more than one character, it's followed by whitespace and even the character after the dot and the whitespace is an uppercase character. I think it's simply impossible to capture such cases in a regex since you would simply have to know if it's an abbreviation or not.

Answer (score -1):

try `$str = preg_replace("/[\.](+[0-9])/", "$1", $str);`